# PhpStorm does not support yaf's init method

Tags: phpstorm, yaf

In other class, PhpStorm can identify `__construct()` function, but in yaf controller it can not identify the initialization method `init()`, resulting in the `init()` can not trace initialization operation.

```
class TestController extends Yaf_Controller_Abstract{
    private $model;
    public function init() {
        $this->model = new TestModel();
    }

    public function test(){
        $this->model->testDeclaration();
    }
}

class TestModel{
    public function testDeclaration(){
    }
}
```

In this example, I want use '`go to declaration`' from test function `$this->model->testDeclaration();` to `testDeclaration()` function in `TestModel` class. But it does not work.

PhpStorm tells me:

> Cannot find declaration to go to

How can I use 'go to declaration' correctly here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In other class, PhpStorm can identify `__construct()` function, but in yaf controller it can not identify the initialization method `init()`, resulting in the `init()` can not trace initialization operation.

PhpStorm has special treatment for `__constructor()` -- it tracks what type class variable/property will get if it will have any assignment operations within the method body.

For example, in this code it knows that `$this->model` will be instance of `TestModel` class -- IDE keeps this info even outside of the `__construct()` method body.

For other methods, like `init()` in your case, such info gets discarded outside (so it's local to the method body only).

---

You can easily resolve this by using simple PHPDoc comment with `@var` tag where you will provide type hint for `model` property:

```
/** @var \TestModel Optional description here */
private $model;
```

Make a habit of providing type hint for all properties/class variables, even if IDE autodetects its' type -- it helps IDE in long run.

https://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/var.html

Comment: Thank you very much, this way can be

Comment: @张轩铭 If it solved your issue that consider marking this answer as Accepted.